# Predictive Density for Dirichlet Multinomial

Tags: bayesian, dirichlet-distribution, conjugate-prior, dirichlet-process

I am wondering what the predictive distribution of a Dirichlet-Multinomial distribution is.

In this [tutorial](http://rp-www.cs.usyd.edu.au/~mlss/content/mlss2015-adams.pdf) (page 24), the predictive density is simple and something like "pseudo samples."

[image]

However, in this [writeup](http://people.csail.mit.edu/stephentu/writeups/dirichlet-conjugate-prior.pdf), the predictive density is rather complicated.

[image]

I can walk through the latter formula, but do not come to the former one. (It does work from my side for multinoulli/categorical distributions, but not multinomial with N>2).

Can anyone give some references? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first slide applies the general result of the second slide to a case when $$y=\overbrace{(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)}^{1\text{ at }\kappa\text{th position}}$$ with different notations, since [in the second slide] $\alpha'_j=\alpha_j+n_j$ and $y^{(j)}=n_j\in\{0,1\}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\prod_{j=1}^K \Gamma(y^{(j)}+1)}&=\dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(y^{(\kappa)}+1)}=\dfrac{n!}{1}\\
\dfrac{\prod_{j=1}^K \Gamma(y^{(j)}+\alpha_j')}{\prod_{j=1}^K\Gamma(\alpha_j')}&=\dfrac{\Gamma(1+\alpha_\kappa')}{\Gamma(\alpha_\kappa')}=\alpha_\kappa+n_\kappa\\
\end{align*}
and the middle ratio does not depend on $y$. 
Hence $$\mathbb{P}(y=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0))\propto \alpha_\kappa+n_\kappa$$which normalises as
$$\mathbb{P}(y_\kappa=1)=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}(y_\kappa=1)}{\sum_{k=1}^K \mathbb{P}(y_k=1)}=\dfrac{ \alpha_\kappa+n_\kappa}{\sum_{k=1}^K \{\alpha_k+n_k\}}=\dfrac{ \alpha_\kappa+n_\kappa}{\sum_{k=1}^K \alpha_k+n}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. If I am understanding correctly, the first slide works with multinomial distributions where N=1, i.e., a categorical distributions. Am I right?

Comment: May I make it more clear? The first slide, which I was confused about, predicts the density for a **single** (N=1) next draw (although the training samples are multinomial distributions with N which can be greater than 2.) Am I right now?

Comment: Hi Xi'an, I am currently having trouble in thinking about conjugate prior for Dirichlet processes. Could you please, perhaps, share some quick sort on [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310886/conjugacy-of-dirichlet-process)? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, I'm mainly in engineering background, so if that's too complicated for me, I may feel like skipping that.